# Can't get past installing debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to create a new Rails project and when I run rails new appname it tells me

```
Could not find debugger-1.6.8 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then when I run bundle install I get this error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141213-76431-12dyum4.rb extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1401:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./214/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1401:in `open'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1401:in `copy_file'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:483:in `copy_file'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:400:in `block in cp'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1579:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1593:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1577:in `fu_each_src_dest'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:399:in `cp'
  from extconf.rb:83:in `block in '
  from extconf.rb:82:in `each'
  from extconf.rb:82:in `'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

I know that debugger doesn't work with Ruby 2.1.4, so how do i get bundler to stop trying to install it? Do i have to use a rails application template?

Comment: What is your Rails version? 4.1.8 doesn't include `debugger` by default, it's commented out.

Comment: looks like you are missing some development headers. Does the content of /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out  give any clues?

Comment: I believe I'm using 4.1.8 , so if its commented out, shouldn't I not be getting that error?

Comment: gem_make out gives me the same error that i printed above, character limits wont let me print the whole thing again

Comment: @PeteyT I run `gem install debugger` and it gives me the same output. Since my environment is fine (I'm sure of it), `debugger` is just not supported by this Ruby (MRI 2.1.4p265) and `byebug` should be used instead.

Comment: @D-side so whenever I run `rails new appname` it gives me this same error, how can i get it to use byebug instead?

Comment: What does `rails -v` say?

Comment: `Could not find debugger-1.6.8 in any of the sources`

`Run "bundle install" to install missing gems.`

Comment: I see. Run this `rails -v` **outside** of any project.

Comment: That was helpful, it turned out I'd had gemfiles in my desktop and user folder and they were giving the debugger that wanted to use now I'm getting this error
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:26:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
 from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:31:in `default_lockfile'
 from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler.rb:253:in `default_lockfile'
 from /Users/username/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>

Answer (score 2):

So for this exact case -- comment out or remove it and any gems that depend on it (look at `Gemfile.lock`) from your `Gemfile` at the root of your project, then run `bundle install`.

Rails 4.1.8 actually generates an app's `Gemfile` with `debugger` commented out, so it should already work fine.

If you actually need a debugger, you can use [`byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug), a replacement for `debugger` for Ruby 2.0+. In the upcoming Rails 4.2.0 release it's [already baked into the generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d8a4e482202bc8d42a16b2311598d49d34304bd6).

When creating a new app, you can also add an option `-B` or `--skip-bundle` to **not** run `bundle install` after creating an  app skeleton. Then you can fix your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` yourself in the project's folder. That only saves you a bit of time though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this failure is '**byebug**' gem which is present in your Gemfile .you can see it in your 'develpement & test' group of Gemfile which looks something like

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
```

'byebug' has the same functionality as 'debugger' - Anyone interested in documentation can visit [Github](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) .